# Angular two-way binding vs method binding

Tags: angularjs

Let's assume we got OuterDirective and InnerDirective. InnerDirective is displaying temp which is provided by OuterDirective like:

```
<outer-directive>
  <inner-directive temp="temp" />
</outer-directive>
```

1) In inner directive we can set up two way binding: temp: '=' and in inner directive tpl use {{ temp }}

Or

2) we can use method binding "&" like temp: '&' and in inner directive tpl {{ temp() }}

The temp is changing so we need to update inner directive.

- Is the second method proper at all?
- Which one would be better in terms of resources ?

Comment: What is the purpose of your outer directive? Is it supposed to interrect with your `temp` variable at all?

Comment: temp is caluculated in outer directive, inner just displays temp value (so in this term '=' binding is not need as it needs read only access

Comment: Then you don't have to use a function at all : `&` will do what you want with any arbitrary value.

Comment: I have updated my answer, now that I think I understood your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the first case, `temp` can be an arbitrary variable which is provided by the `OuterDirective`'s scope. The `=` means that updating that value in the `InnerDirective`'s scope will update it as well in the `OuterDirective`'s scope.

The second case is possible, you can pass everything you want, one-way, to an attribute marked by `&`.

Using `temp` in both inner and outer scope is a bit confusing, so I'm going to use `outer` and `inner` instead.

**Let's suppose `outer()` is a function defined in your outer scope, returning an arbitrary result you want to display in your directive and `inner` is your inner directive attribute.**

```
<outer-directive>
   <inner-directive inner="{{outer()}}" />
</outer-directive>
```

This will work like a charm if you want one-way binding. The confusing part is that `&` attributes need `{{}}` to bind to a value, when `=` attributes don't.

Now you can use

```
<div>{{inner}}</div>
```

directly.

You can also pass your `outer` function so that it is called *inside* your inner directive, but that's a bit trickier.

If you want to know more about this, I recommand you read the "Creating a Directive that Wraps Other Elements" in [Angular's documentation about directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), there is a very good example of what it can do at the end of the section (you want to look at the very last example).

Here is a brief excerpt :

> We saw earlier how to use =attr in the scope option, but in the above example, we're using &attr instead. The & binding allows a directive to trigger evaluation of an expression in the context of the original scope, at a specific time. Any legal expression is allowed, including an expression which contains a function call. Because of this, & bindings are ideal for binding callback functions to directive behaviors.
>
> Best Practice: use &attr in the scope option when you want your directive to expose an API for binding to behaviors.

Comment: I tried {{ outer }} but it did not work - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdWQzB - unless i messed it a bit ?

Comment: I have also modified it http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLpJqg - but in that case even at start provideTemp is run 10 times ??

Comment: You did it the way it's supposed to be ;) : And yes : the callback will be executed as many times as Angular thinks it is useful to call `scope.$apply` on your directive to refresh the content (each time it thinks something might have changed). If you had put it in an event handler, of course, it would have been executed only once per event. But here as it's bound to some content, it is recalculated by `scope.$apply()`, just as many times as angular would check an `=` attribute for changes to update both scopes.

Comment: Alright. I have modified it so it only uses your `outer` function once per second, so that `scope.$apply` is called only once per second. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqpQXg  You could bind this to events instead, for instance, in order to controll *when* the function is called.

Comment: Ok so this is answer: there is no performance difference between using '=' binding and '&' binding with function return value as the function is called as many times as angular checks internally binding '=". Is that right?

Comment: I assume if for some reason we would like to minimize function calculation cycle, we could use $interval solution ?

Comment: Well Angular is quite clever when it comes to call `$scope.apply`. The thing is, in the first case, `$scope.apply` will be called each time something changes in the scope or parent scope, and be inert otherwise, while in the second case, it will always be called no matter what on a regular basis, consuming resources even if nothing has changed. So it's really up to you, depending on your function, its complexity, and the need for it to refresh.